# Query optimization using ORDER BY column in index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

we have to query a table like the below:

```
SELECT * FROM table where A = x and B = y order BY C DESC limit 1
```

Basically, we have to get the most recent row on column C

To optimize the query, I have added an index to the table `(A, B, C NULLS LAST)`

From the query plan, it looks like, it is not using this index for the order as its sorting over the above index results.

```
 Limit  (cost=10000000008.18..10000000008.18 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=0.514..0.514 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=10000000008.18..10000000008.18 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=0.513..0.513 rows=1 loops=1)
         Sort Key: created_at DESC
         Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
         ->  Index Scan using index_name on table  (cost=0.14..8.16 rows=1 width=268) (actual time=0.472..0.488 rows=44 loops=1)
               Index Cond: ((A = '41'::text) AND (B = 0))
               Filter: (A ~~ '41'::text)
 Planning Time: 1.658 ms
 Execution Time: 1.127 ms
(9 rows)
```

I am looking to optimize my query, I am new to indexes, can someone please help here.

**edit**

Table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE attributes (
    id text NOT NULL COLLATE pg_catalog."C",
    product_id smallint,
    from_number text,
    to_number text,
    created_at timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now() NOT NULL,
    last_updated_at timestamp without time zone,
    request_id text,
    status smallint
);
```

Current indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX index_attributes_on_from_number ON attributes USING btree (from_number);

CREATE INDEX index_attributes_on_status_product_id ON attributes USING btree (status, product_id);
```

Index I am planning to add:

```
CREATE INDEX index_attributes_on_request_id_and_product_id_and_created_at ON attributes USING btree (request_id, product_id, created_at DESC NULLS LAST) WHERE (request_id IS NOT NULL);
```

The use case is to pick the last created row with a particular request-id and product-id. Looking for help what will be the ideal index for this case. I am noticing in the query plan that it is not using the sorted order of created_at in the index but doing an explicit sort over the index results.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Without knowledge about the data in these three columns, it's hard to help you. Especially because the query is already pretty fast, just over 2 milliseconds. When X has the most unique values, that one should be first in the index. Unclear why X in the query plan becomes an A (or B) in your question. Could you share the real (and complete) table and index definitions?

Comment: I have updated the question to handle the confusion around X/Y. I am currently working on a small subset of data on local, that's why optimal query times. But wanted to understand what will be the proper index for this use case and if there is any mistake in that. A is the correct column to have the most unique values.

Comment: In a set of 1000 records, when A has 100 unique values and B has just 10, the index should use (A, B, C). When B has more unique values, it should be (B, A, C). Just try it and see the differences

Comment: sounds like the problem is in the "composition of indices"...why should a (A, B, C) index help with this query? an index on (A) + an index on (B) + an index on (C) would make sense, also combining the first two with the last: (A, C) + (B, C)..

Comment: Yes, I am using the index in the same order (A, B, C). Tried the opposite and yes it did worsen a little for the subset of data I have

Comment: Please show us a real table, real query, and real plan.  You can anonymize them of course, but then verify that they still do what you say they do afterwards.  Your table name is illegal, your query is a syntax error, and if it were not there is no way it would generate that plan.

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question